# why clear cache solve "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"?

Tags: google-chrome, web, browser

I got un error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" while refresh my application local, after search on google, I've got un solution who recommends to clear the browser's data such as cache files and that works.

However, there is no explanation about why that works and why the cache cause the errors so that I could avoid this next time.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without any code.

If data is cached and you refresh the page, the cached content will stay after the refresh causing an error.

Try using Shift + F5 / Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh page, ignoring cached content

(Cmd + Shift + R for Mac)

Comment: It's also hard to show the code, cause I have no idea if this caused by code or browser, but clear cache did help to remove "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error, just trying to find the reason

Comment: I understand, I would say there doesn't necessarily have to be a problem in the code, however there might be a problem with how it uses for example cookies.
If you're using JS/react, i would start looking into the states you're using and calling, other than that using Shift + f5 is always a good ide when testing an application in the browser.